# Proportional gain with DC offset in LED driver circuit saturates output

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

I have a negative feedback loop with \$K_P = 10\$ for a LED driver circuit:

[image]

I've used \$R_{fb} = 9k\$ and another resistor from the LED  to the negative terminal of \$1k\$ in order to get a proportional gain of 10, so that for an input of -0.2 to 0.2 V, I get the voltage output at output terminal of Op-Amp to be -2 to 2V. This works only for positive input, while negative input voltage saturates the output. Also, I need to shift the voltage at the output by 2V to 0-4V from -2 to 2V using a resistor divider strictly. I've never used a voltage divider as a level shifter, so can someone help me out in this? How do I fine tune the \$K_{p}\$ for the negative input voltage as I have mentioned, since it saturates the output?

Comment: That 1k resistor does not set gain the way you believe. What you have built is a voltage controlled current source, which is determined only by RFB. It will saturate at negative voltages because no negative current can flow through the diode. Look up a difference amplifier circuit, which will do what you want including the gain and the level shift.

Comment: In that case, how do I set up a voltage divider to get a \$K_p\$ of around 10? I'm absolutely new to feedback control systems, and I believed that it could work just like a non-inverting amplifier, but it doesn't. Can you help me out in this please?

Answer (score 1):

difference amplifier to shift +0.2 .. -0.2 V to 0 .. 4 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm1GKK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can we do it without a difference amplifier? Using a three resistor voltage divider bias to shift the voltage level?

Comment: @AmpliFire It is probably possible by tying IN+ to GND and adding a third resistor between IN- and the negative supply. Try and figure it out with some simulator such as the circuitlab (you can use the simulate button under my schematic)

Comment: Well circuitlab is a paid software.... I've used LTSpice, and done some shifting as well. But I can't obtain the 0-4V output, I've obtained around 0-3V with some shifting. If you could give me some hint regarding setting the resistor values, I can proceed from there.

Comment: I have connected a resistor from the output to a voltage divider bias connected to the positive rail supply and ground.

Comment: I've solved the saturation problem, by separating the entire thing into two functional components, the P-gain device and the LED Driver. This has helped me to solve the problem explicitly.

Comment: I just need to shift the output using the 3 resistor bias, that's it.

Comment: Ive updated it to use only a 3-resistor divider

Comment: Circuitlab is free if you use it via the link under the schematic. But of course LTspice is a better choice anyway